# System.Web.Services cannot be added to VB.NET project in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

I am working on a VB.NET project in Visual Studio Community 2019, using Windows forms. I want to populate a DataGridView with data from a DataSet. But I get an error upon creating the DataSet, saying that "System.Web.Services could not be added to the project". The DataSet is then created, but I cannot chose it as a DataSource for the DataGridView. Maybe it is worthwhile to mention that my project is not intended to deal with anything online, so I wonder why should I need any Web Service stuff. How I can get rid of the error, or at least populate the DataGridView with my DataSet?

I am noticing -thanks Jon!- the following in the VB code (some 600 auto-generated lines) belonging to the DataSet:

```
Me.DataSetName = "DataSet1"
Me.Prefix = ""
Me.Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd"
```

and further down:

```
Dim any1 As Global.System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaAny = New Global.System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaAny()
any1.Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

I do not know how to bind the data to the grid view by hand, I was trying to use the GUI for doing it, which is not offering me the DateSet as source.

For the DataGrid view, I dragged it in from the toolbox where it can be found under "All Windows Forms"->"DataGridView".

Comment: Make sure you're not trying to use WebForms Gridview control. Show us your code where you are creating your dataset and attempting to bind to the DataGridView

Comment: I worked now around it by creating a xml which I can load as DataSet: ```dim xmlfile as XmlReader ds=new DataSet ds.ReadXml(xmlfile) DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Table(0)```

Comment: @pantha-rhey you can share your solution by posting a answer, then accept it, so that other members with similar questions can find the solution quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

worked now around the GUI way of creating a DataSet by

- creating an xml which I can load as DataSet

```
<NewDataSet>
<Table0><col0>entry0row0</col0><col1>entry1row0</col1></Table0>
<Table0><col0>entry0row1</col0><col1>entry1row1</col1></Table0>
</NewDataSet>
```

- reading in the xml by:

```
Imports System.xml

ds = New DataSet
Using xmlFile As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(filename, New XmlReaderSettings())
ds.ReadXml(xmlFile)
End Using
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Table(0)
```